# check and protect a thread in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, c++17

Currently, I created a simple thread to clear memory:

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        CreateThread(0, 0, test, 0, 0, 0);
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Code:

```
DWORD WINAPI test(LPVOID lpvParam) {
memo: 
    Sleep(10000);
    SetProcessWorkingSetSize(GetCurrentProcess(), 102400, 614400);
    goto memo;  
}
```

Is there any way to protect this thread? And prevent it from being paused with some external program (such as Process Hacker 2)?

Example: if the thread is running, returns true, if it is externally paused or interrupted, returns false and closes the program with `ExitProcess()`?

I tried different methods like

`std::thread`
`thread.join()`.
`thread.joinable()`

None of them worked.

Comment: It is unwise to create threads from inside `DllMain`. See [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices), which has this to say: "You should never perform the following tasks from within `DllMain`: ... Call `CreateThread`."

Comment: If there's an external program that can pause your threads, that same external program can patch whatever method you use to detect whether the thread is healthy, and have that method always return true.

Comment: I had already read about it, but the point is that regardless of the way I call the thread, the problem itself is the fact that third parties can pause the thread with any program as mentioned above (process hacker2) is one of them!

Comment: Igor Tandetnik
so there is no solution?

Comment: One solution would be to run the thread only on a computer that you have exclusive access to (and the hackers do not); e.g. on a private server somewhere and not on random users' PCs.

Comment: Don't allow rogue programs to run on your system? Insecure computer is insecure.

Comment: these threads check some program pointers, if the values have changed from 0 to 1 for example, and the program runs on the client computer then they circumvent this by using programs to pause or terminate the threads

Comment: Use your application business logic thread for your checks then. So that pausing the thread renders your application unusable.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik "*It is unwise to create threads from inside DllMain*" - it is OK to *create* a thread, as long as you don't *wait* on the thread after.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin
I don't know if I understand exactly what you're proposing, but I'll research it!

Comment: @voidtech to do what you are asking, you would have to create a watchdog to monitor your thread to see if it pauses/terminates unexpectedly. But the hacker could just pause/terminate the watchdog first. Catch 22. So no, there is really not a good way to protect your threads from external tampering. If the hacker has sufficient access rights to reach into your process in the first place, they can do whatever they want.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau yes, unfortunately everything indicates that there is no 100% way to fix this, only ways to work around it until the hacker discovers a new method! I've researched a lot about this and everything comes to the same conclusion as you said :(

Comment: *"I have a question"* -- I already got this much from the fact that you posted a question. Instead of squandering the valuable first sentence of your post, perhaps you should start by asking the question? (Getting right to the point is one of the tips in [ask].) When people view the question list, they see the title and the first sentence or so of the body. Appropriately packing useful information into that part of your question can help a question get desirable attention. Use that space to inform readers what the general topic/scope of your question is.

Comment: Can you modify the source code of the application, or is your dll intended to load into arbitrary 3rd-party applications?

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin it is loaded in a 3rd party application, it is loaded in a third-party application, I have no way to change the source code of this application, just work with what I have!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik [Does creating a thread from DllMain deadlock or doesn't it?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070904-00/?p=25283)

Comment: @IInspectable I don't mind repeating my comment on the poor idea you keep posting around. That blog post is an anecdote about how one can get away with not following the best practices in one limited scenario in 2007. That anecdote doesn't generalize beyond that use case nor does it apply to Windows versions released since then. The best practices document, on the other hand, is the authoritative source coming directly from the vendor, any divergent 3rd-party documentation is rather irrelevant. Your opinion based on out-of-date 3rd-party anecdote is worthless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> prevent thread from being paused with some external program (such as Process Hacker 2)?

Instead of creating a new thread to run your code periodically, create a waitable timer with `CreateWaitableTimer` and schedule it with `SetWaitableTimer`. The timer runs the callback in the thread that called [`SetWaitableTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-setwaitabletimer), so that there is no other thread to pause.

That also solves the problem that threads must not be created in `DllMain`.

Comment: "*The timer runs the callback in the thread that called SetWaitableTimer*" - yes, but only when that thread is in an alertable state, which requires extra coding to get into that state. That is not something most apps do by default. And if the timer is created in a DLL, there is no guarantee that the app thread that is loading the DLL will every be alertable

Comment: @RemyLebeau Once the dll is loaded into the process, it can also intercept the win32 api calls listed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/alertable-i-o to force the alertable flag on. It is not clear whether OP can modify the app source code, or his dll is inteded to work with any 3rd-party application.

Comment: I'll try to apply this idea you suggested, thank you and everyone who gave your answers, thank you!

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I assume you mean intercepting the **NON**-alertable functions to make them call their alertable counterparts instead? It wouldn't make sense to intercept the alertable functions if the app is already calling them.

Comment: @voidtech For applications with windows message loop, `SetTimer` can also work.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are quite right. The non-alertable non-`Ex` calls must be turned into alertable ones, `Ex` calls must force `alertable` flag on.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin that assumes the app is calling those functions to begin with. If it doesn't, or doesn't call them frequently enough, then intercepting them won't help anything.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The app will likely have a windows message loop or do some I/O. These calls can be intercepted to put the calling thread into the alertable state. It is hard to concieve a useful app without any I/O. Unless it is a pure Haskell app.

Comment: *"threads must not be created in `DllMain`"* - Citation needed.

Comment: @IInspectable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices

Comment: That link says: *"Creating a thread can work"*. [Does creating a thread from DllMain deadlock or doesn't it?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070904-00/?p=25283) provides rationale that's missing from the documentation. The short of it is: Creating a thread poses no risk whatsoever.

Comment: @IInspectable You already posted the link to the blog post. And that blog posts refers to the very same best practices. I wouldn't take your word that's it is safe and would ask you to rework the code if it didn't follow the best practices, it wouldn't pass code review in any decent team.

Comment: @IInspectable That blog post is an anecdote about how one can get away with not following the best practices in one limited scenario in 2007. That anecdote doesn't generalize beyond that use case nor does it apply to Windows versions released since then. The best practices document, on the other hand, is the authoritative source coming directly from the vendor, any divergent 3rd-party documentation is rather irrelevant. Your opinion based on out-of-date 3rd-party anecdote is worthless.

Comment: The blog post explains the reason behind the *"DLL Best Practices"* (which are neither formal documentation nor authoritative). The reason is that `DllMain` runs under the loader lock and you cannot execute any code that will (directly or indirectly) attempt to acquire the loader lock again. Creating a thread will not. If you insist that the *"DLL Best Practices"* were contractual and/or authoritative, then you'll have to also acknowledge the exemption. All that aside, creating a thread from `DllMain` makes for a *far* more robust solution than your proposed answer.

Comment: @IInspectable The OP explains why he doesn't want to create a thread.

Comment: I fail to see anything in this proposed answer that helps with that. All it does is provide a brittle solution to run code on a different thread that's not under the client's control. Now you have to protect someone else's thread. You've merely avoided addressing the real issue.